# how to solve the stackoverflow exception when the activity view nest too deep

Tags: java, android

now i meet a problem , in my android application , my activity layout is too deep, and it cause the problem like below.

```
java.lang.StackOverflowError
android.text.TextLine.measureRun
android.text.TextLine,measure
android.text.Layout.getLineExtent()
android.text.layout.drawText()
android.widget.TextView.OnDraw()
```

someone suggest me to cut the level of layout, but my application is special, 
i could control it ,because i am not the designer of application view, i just 
apply the interface and basic control for any one to use.
someone said that we can also modify the build.prop file parameter to solve the problem , wish someone can help me , thanks a lotherecation .

Comment: too deep? how many levels?

Comment: at least 30 level and it will be more deep possible,  thanks a lot

Comment: whaaaaat? 30 levels? you should find another guy who creates your UI, i cannot imagine a layout that has more then hmmm 5 levels at most

Comment: the layout is not create by me ,it is created by someone others ,they use  too much useless nest, they just use the interface i suppled and i cannot control